# SSIS - truncate table when other table contains data with certain value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have 2 tables on 2 different databases.

When Table A from Database A contains data and a certain value is written in a specific column, then I need to truncate table B on database B and copy data from table A to table B.

So, When table A looks like:

```
ID | column2
1  | null
2  | null
3  | null
```

then we don't do anything.

If table A looks like

```
ID | column2
1  | value
2  | value
3  | value
```

then Table B gets truncated and the data from table A gets copied to table B.

I tried this with a Execute SQL task, but that only works for when all tables are from the same database.

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to do this within SSIS, run an `Execute SQL Task` in your Control Flow that does a count of the records in `Table A` that meet your criteria and sets a variable to either `true` if there are or `false` if there aren't any.

Create a connection from your `Execute SQL Task` to however you want to execute your `truncate` and `insert` statements.  Right click on the arrow and select `Edit...` to set the `Condition` that if the variable you just set is `True` or `False` to either follow that path or not.

Create a connection to the next step in your Control Flow if there are any, and change the `LogicalAnd` property of this connection to `false`.  You should see the arrow change to demostrate the different precedence behaviour.  Create another connection from your original `Execute SQL Task` to this next step in your control flow.  This arrow should also look different.

What will now happen when you run this package is that the variable will be set with either `true` or `false` on whether or not to `truncate` and `insert` and then follow the correct path in your Control Flow.  Once either of these paths hits the next steps (Of which only one should ever execute), your package will continue as normal.